# WiiUse library and MAC El Capitan Undefined symbols

Tags: c, static-libraries, wiiuse

I'm trying to install WiiUse (https://github.com/rpavlik/wiiuse) on my El Capitan.

First I downloaded all the git, then I followed the instruction and when I try to run the example I get this error:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Sounds a bit like you're trying to use a 32-bit library in a 64-bit program. But we need more info to be sure; what is the exact code, how are you compiling it, the exact output, ...

Comment: I'm using this library: https://github.com/rpavlik/wiiuse
I have no clue on how to look if 32 or 64
The exact code is their example: https://github.com/rpavlik/wiiuse/blob/master/example/example.c

The only different is that to make the library working I have done: cmake ../src and not the command given in their tutoria because it gave me policy problem.